# Why does the Amazon dropdown menu load last?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, web-app, actions

Following scenario: I log in to Amazon webpage and want to go to Prime Video. The link to Prime Video is under the main menu at the top of the page.

However, the dropdown menu is the last thing to load. I have to wait until the full page is loaded before I can switch to Prime Video. Why has Amazon designed it like this? It seems like bad usability but I presume Amazon has analyzed all these kinds of things.

Comment: Presumably it is just loaded asynchronously to allow the rest of the page to load quicker. Amazon likely decided it was more important to prioritize loading products over menu options as products are what pay their bills.

Comment: That sounds plausible

Comment: Asking why company X has done something is not a question that we can answer. Unless the actual designer who built it is a member of the site then all we can do is speculate, hence 'primarily opinion based'. I suggest contacting Amazon themselves rather than Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok :) You're right ... should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're looking at, but there is two ways to get to Amazon Prime Video page;

In the header (underneath the logo), under the "Shop by Department" dropdown menu;

1) **Shop by Department > Amazon Video**

Or under "Your Account" dropdown menu;

2) **Your Account > Your Prime Video**

I don't find it difficult to find it following either one of the methods to navigate to it!

They have placed it right under "Your Account" to declare to the account holder that they've an Amazon Prime not to mention that it would be quite obvious for the user to guess!

The other link under "Shop by Department" is because they're still selling DVDs and movie related goods, so perhaps they can convince the user instead of spending so much on each DVD or whatever, they make the user to think "Ah it actually works out cheaper if I opt in for an Amazon Prime"...

And of course there are surely other marketing reasons behind it...

Comment: I was referring to 2) Your Account > Your Prime Video. I didn't know about option 1).